# Maven checksum failed

Tags: maven-2, archiva

I am working on a project that uses Maven as the build tool. I am using version 2.2.1 of the tool. Recently a coworker mentioned that he couldn't build the project because of checksum errors. I wasn't getting these errors so I deleted my local repository. Sure enough, I also got the checksum errors on the next attempt to build. We are using Archiva as our central repository, so I uploaded the jars again hoping to resolve the issue. No luck. What could be causing these errors and how do I resolve them?

```
Downloading: http://artifactory/archiva/repository/maven-repo/org/springframework/ws/spring-
ws/1.5.8/spring-ws-1.5.8.pom
427b downloaded  (spring-ws-1.5.8.pom)
[WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '14d6901e3f251f5d312b9be726c75a
68f78045ac'; remote = '659bbed2c2dae12e9dbb65f8cad8fce1a1ea0845' - RETRYING
Downloading: http://artifactory/archiva/repository/maven-repo/org/springframework/ws/spring-
ws/1.5.8/spring-ws-1.5.8.pom
427b downloaded  (spring-ws-1.5.8.pom)
[WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '14d6901e3f251f5d312b9be726c75a
68f78045ac'; remote = '659bbed2c2dae12e9dbb65f8cad8fce1a1ea0845' - IGNORING
Downloading: http://artifactory/archiva/repository/maven-repo/com/xyz/abc/3.0.20090929_
attachment_fixes/abc-3.0.20090929_attachment_fixes.pom
435b downloaded  (abc-3.0.20090929_attachment_fixes.pom)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manually deleted the artifacts from Archiva and used Archiva to upload them again. This solved my problem. There appeared to be duplicate POMs, JARs, etc in Archiva for the versions that were giving the checksum errors.

Comment: It solves the problem, but for how long?    Did you find that it returned or did you make additional changes to the pom or settings?

Answer (score 9):

The problem appears to be in how the maven client is deploying artifacts to your central repository (Archiva).  It's using HTTP and in certain situations will corrupt the checksum signature of the file.

Try changing your local maven settings file to look something like this, which for me was located in `~/.m2/settings.xml`

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>my-server</id>
      <configuration>
        <httpConfiguration>
          <put>
            <params>
              <param>
                <name>http.authentication.preemptive</name>
                <value>%b,true</value>
              </param>
            </params>
          </put>
        </httpConfiguration>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

After you make that change, redeploy the artifacts to your central repo, then try to run `mvn dependency:resolve` in your local project to see if the checksum errors still happen.

Here's a thread about this problem: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4301

Comment: I ran into this issue because my deployment server (as specified in my pom's "distributionManagement" section) had an HTTP://myserver URL, however the server was redirecting to HTTPS. Switching the distributionManagement URL over to HTTPS fixed the issue.

Comment: @Ring Please also add this as a separate answer. Helped me, could help others :)

Answer (score 7):

The artifact resolver is (still, even in 3.0.4 apparently) not thread safe:

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4742

try building with:

-Dmaven.artifact.threads=1

When I build with this option in 3.0.4 in a project that displays checksum errors (for log4j), all of the checksum errors disappear.

It should apply to 2.2.1 as well.

(edit: file this answer under 'hiding false negatives')

Answer (score 4):

Did you try to change the *Checksum* policies in the [proxy connector](http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.0.2/adminguide/proxy-connectors.html) to '*fix*' instead of '*ignore*'?

Answer (score 0):

While using a single thread as described bu Rondo below allowed the build complete without error, in the end I found that my work space was corrupted.  Possibly due to an interrupted build.  I wiped out the work space and created a clean one from the source code manager and everything worked fine again.