# Problems with release:perform. Checksum validation failed

Tags: maven, maven-3, artifactory

I´m trying to run the release plugin in my application, the release:prepare is being done correctly but when I try to run de release:perform. I´ll give you some sections of the error:

```
[INFO] Uploaded: http://172.18.102.23:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local/br/fucapi/ads/ads/0.0.9/ads-0.0.9.pom (3 KB at 5.5 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://172.18.102.23:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local/br/fucapi/ads/ads/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] [WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected GIF89a????!?,D; but is 2daeaa8b5f19f0bc209d976c02bd6acb51b00b0a for http://172.18.102.23:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local/br/fucapi/ads/ads/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] [WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected GIF89a????!?,D; but is 2daeaa8b5f19f0bc209d976c02bd6acb51b00b0a for http://172.18.102.23:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local/br/fucapi/ads/ads/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: http://172.18.102.23:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local/br/fucapi/ads/ads/maven-metadata.xml (43 B at 1.3 KB/sec)

[INFO] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 5.672s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: Mon Jun 04 11:08:32 GMT-04:00 2012
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 6M/28M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project ads: Failed to update metadata br.fucapi.ads:ads/maven-metadata.xml: Could not parse metadata C:\Documents and Settings\JOSEBARBOSA\.m2\repository\br\fucapi\ads\ads\maven-metadata-release.xml: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not G (position: START_DOCUMENT seen G... @1:1) -> [Help 1]
[INFO] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project ads: Failed to update metadata br.fucapi.ads:ads/maven-metadata.xml: Could not parse metadata C:\Documents and Settings\JOSEBARBOSA\.m2\repository\br\fucapi\ads\ads\maven-metadata-release.xml: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not G (position: START_DOCUMENT seen G... @1:1) 

[INFO] Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to update metadata br.fucapi.ads:ads/maven-metadata.xml: Could not parse metadata C:\Documents and Settings\JOSEBARBOSA\.m2\repository\br\fucapi\ads\ads\maven-metadata-release.xml: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not G (position: START_DOCUMENT seen G... @1:1) 
[INFO]  at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:193)
```

1) I tried to clean my repository.
2) I put this configuration in my properties.

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```

3) I try this topic: [Maven checksum failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765959/maven-checksum-failed) using "mvn dependency:resolve".
4)Try the following topic: [Using Maven with QT Jambi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324677/using-maven-with-qt-jambi) using "checksumPolicy" in my settings.xml

...but this issues didn´t work.

Please, don´t know what to do to fix this problem, anyone ever had this?

Answer (score 2):

```
daeaa8b5f19f0bc209d976c02bd6acb51b0
```

indicates, that the response is SSL-encoded. The URL

```
http://172.18.102.23:8080/artifactory/
```

is from the configuration. Either change the protocol to

```
https
```

or change the URL.

Answer (score 0):

This is also an error that, unintuitively, can be thrown as a result of your server being inaccessible. Curl'ing the url mvn is attempting to connect to could save you some time troubleshooting this.